# Confusion in reading file using FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, asp.net

which i used earlier (FileuploadControl tool used)

inside button click method

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);

    string lines;
    string root = Server.MapPath("~/");
    string Template = root + filename;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Template))
    {
        while ((lines = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            list.Add(lines); // Add to list.
    }
    //file is now in list
    //MORE IMPORTANT CODE
}
```

But now I am just using FolderDialog

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
folderDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
DialogResult result = folderDialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
    textBox8.Text = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
    Environment.SpecialFolder root = folderDialog.RootFolder
    //...
}
```

How can i read the file so that i can only use the FolderBrowserDialog to read an entire file and extract data?

Comment: FolderBrowserDialog is a windows common dialog. Not an asp.net control. Thus, this run on the server, not on the client side. To be simple, what you are trying to do is not possible natively (maybe with a HTML5 drag'n drop but I'm not sure)

Comment: I am doing the same application On web and for local machine....i was able to do it as a web application but i am finding some difficulties in doing it on client side..But it would be great if I reuse the same code by just using FileuploadControl for web and FolderBrowserDialog for client side

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working in Windows Forms now if you are using `FolderDialog`.

You should use better `OpenFileDialog` if you want the user to check a FILE, not a Folder.

You can read the file using `System.IO classes` once you have the path.

If the file is text for example you can do:

```
string FinalPath = OpenFileDialog.FileName;

string Text= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FinalPath);
```

you can also read the file into byte()

```
byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FinalPath);
```